# Encode and Decode a string on Objective C

Tags: objective-c, encryption, encoding

I use below code to encode and decode a string on objective C. The encoding is good, I debug and see that it throw a hash string when input is @"1". But when I try to decode this hash string, it return nil.

Please help me.

```
+(NSString *)encrypt: (NSString*) input
{

    //Base64 Encoding

    char base64Result[32];
    size_t theResultLength = 32;
    Base64EncodeData(input, 20, base64Result, &theResultLength);
    NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithBytes:base64Result length:theResultLength];
    NSString *base64EncodedResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString* decryptedString = [self decrypt:base64EncodedResult];
    return [base64EncodedResult autorelease];
}
+ (NSString *) decrypt:(NSString*) input{

        Byte inputData[[input lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];//prepare a Byte[]
    [[input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] getBytes:inputData];//get the pointer of the data
    size_t inputDataSize = (size_t)[input length];
    size_t outputDataSize = EstimateBas64DecodedDataSize(inputDataSize);//calculate the decoded data size
    Byte outputData[outputDataSize];//prepare a Byte[] for the decoded data
    Base64DecodeData(inputData, inputDataSize, outputData, &outputDataSize);//decode the data
    NSData *theData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:outputData length:outputDataSize];//create a NSData object from the decoded data
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Based off the names of your functions, I really hope you don't think that you are encrypting the data to keep it secure using Base64. There is a really big difference between encryption and encoding.

Comment: also these could be instance methods (via category) on the strings to be encoded/decoded instead of class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you encoding method, you have to convert the input string to a byte buffer and feed that to `Base64EncodeData`:

```
NSData *inputData = [input dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
Base64EncodeData([inputData bytes], [inputData length], base64Result, &theResultLength, NO);
```

(The `NSString *input` argument in the encoding method points to an Objective-C structure, not to a C string. So your encoding method *seems* to work. It encodes *something*, but not the input string. The decoding method then fails at

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

because the decoded data does not contain valid UTF-8.)